# Launching executable via Python

Tags: python, shell

I am trying to launch an executable via a python script which supplies and loop over different arguments.

The executable saves a series of file to disk all with identical names. I would like to use the python script to save the different output in different folder according to the command I supply. My python script looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python    
import subprocess
import csv
import sys

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print 'Give a number for the folder name as an argument'
    quit()


loop_params = [i*0.001 for i in range(100,270,10)]
param1 = 0.0001
param2 = 0.0005
param3 = 0.25
param4 = 0.92
param5 = 0.66
param6 = 0.75
param7 = -1
param8 = 2

arg2 = str(param1)
arg3 = str(param2) #each arg is passed to the program
arg4 = str(param3)
arg5 = str(param4) 
arg6 = str(param5)
arg7 = str(param6)
arg8 = str(param7)
arg9 = str(param8)

new_dir = 'Run'+str(sys.argv[1])
# Remove folder if there and then make it again
subprocess.call(['rm -r '+new_dir+' ; mkdir '+new_dir], shell=True)



for t in loop_params:


xdir = str(t)


   cmd = './main' # executable
   arg1 = str(t) #each arg is passed to the program

   print cmd+" "+arg1+" "+arg2+" "+arg3+" "+arg4+" "+arg5+" "+arg6+" "+arg7+" "+arg8+" "+arg9
   p = subprocess.Popen([cmd,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   out, err =  p.communicate()
   stor_dir = new_dir+'/'+xdir
   #print out
   subprocess.call(['mkdir '+stor_dir], shell=True)
   subprocess.call(['mv *txt '+stor_dir],shell=True)


# Info on the paramters
this_run = "Loop over "+str(arg1)+"\n param1 = "+arg2+"\n param2 = "+arg3+"\n param3 = "+arg4+"\n param4 ="+arg5+"\n param5 ="+arg6+" \n param6 ="+arg7+"\n param7 = "+arg8+"\n param7 = "+arg8

ofile  = open("this_run.info", "wb")
ofile.write(this_run)
ofile.close

subprocess.call(['mv *.info '+new_dir],shell=True)
```

This works fine (albeit, it is probably a very quick and dirty way of doing things): it runs the program with looping over the array `loop_params` create the folder `new_dir` and creates all subfolders in it, moving the files to them.

Problem: if I launch this more then once since the `.\main` executable writes his own file by appending to them and the python script only later moves them to their final folder, they get overwritten and messed up.

I would like to do something like

```
mkdir new_dir
loop ./new_dir/main
[... other loop operations ...]
```

so that files are created in `new_dir` and there is no overwriting. I have tried to copy the executable in the `new_dir` (ok) but if I than use `./new_dir/main` the program always output in the current directory where the python script is launched. I also tried to supply the `cwd = new_dir` option to `subprocess.Popen` but it didn't work.

I am rather a newbie with python and I am trying to adapt a script from somebody else on the project to suit my needs.

Thank you

Comment: Assuming your executable writes files to the current directory, why not just change the current directory in python when you call it?  You could use `os.chdir`, but better to use `cwd=dirname` argument to `subprocess.Popen`.

Comment: By the way, you are calling chile processes all over the place like you would in a shell script.  Don't call things like `rm`, `mkdir`, `mv` when there are python builtins for that.

Comment: Thank you, I have never used python before and working with linux these comes the most natural. I have solved the problem and I will post an answer, if I have time I will try your suggestion as well and add them to the answer.

Comment: I'm not certain what it is you are trying to achieve.  However, could you please raise a comment to me when you have your solution and I will try to suggest improvements.  There are a lot of improvements that can be made to your current script.

Comment: Actually I removed my answer as it was not really working. What I would like to achieve is to be able to run my `./run.py X` with different x and for each one have it create a RunX folder where the program gets executed and files saved and moved indipendently (i.e. without overwriting).

Comment: Where do you want the files moved to?

Comment: To be more clear: ideally I would like that launching the python script `./run.py X`creates a folder structure of this form:

`RunX/xdir/` with the xdir storing the output of the `main xdir param1 param2 ... param 9` that I am launching under the loop. My current script and yours below both do that, but they do so by moving output file after each loop iteration. Launching run.py multiple times will yield files with data from different runs, as they will overwrite each other (because `main` appends to the txt files it produces)

Comment: We could create a directory name with a date/time stamp appended, would that be what you need?

Comment: Nope, the name of the directory is mostly irrelevant.

 The only point is, if I launch two `.py X` and `.py X+1`at the same time each of them will loop launching the executable several time. The executable writes a file called `output.txt`. The same file will be written on by two different processes and the output will get messed up. I would like python to launch the executable 'as if' it was in the final destination folder already.

Comment: I ended up taking your first suggestion, which was there all along, and used os.chdir() before entering the loop =) Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my version.  Mostly it is simple improvements, like removing duplicate `str()` calls, string formatting, and a little optimisation. Removing the external program calls may make a little difference to the performance, but the principle is to avoid creating unnecessary child processes.  This is, after all, one of the major advantages of a language like Python over using a shell.

There are other improvements possible, but I didn't want to go too far.

It does not do everything asked of it, because I can't figure out what else is required:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import csv
import sys

# These added
import os
import shutil
import glob

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    # Write error messages to stderr
    print >>sys.stderr, 'Give a number for the folder name as an argument'
    quit()

# Why not make these strings in the first place?  Also might be easier as a list
param1 = 0.0001
param2 = 0.0005
param3 = 0.25
param4 = 0.92
param5 = 0.66
param6 = 0.75
param7 = -1
param8 = 2

arg2 = str(param1)
arg3 = str(param2) #each arg is passed to the program
arg4 = str(param3)
arg5 = str(param4)
arg6 = str(param5)
arg7 = str(param6)
arg8 = str(param7)
arg9 = str(param8)

# sys.argv is a list of strings
new_dir = 'Run' + sys.argv[1]

# Remove folder if there and then make it again
# No need to use a shell or the rm and mkdir programs
#subprocess.call(['rm -r '+new_dir+' ; mkdir '+new_dir], shell=True)

shutil.rmtree(new_dir, True)
os.mkdir(new_dir)
os.chdir(new_dir)
cmd = './main' # executable, removed outside the loop

# This was 'loop_params' and 't'
for xdir in [str(i*0.001) for i in xrange(100,270,10)]:

   arg1 = xdir  # each arg is passed to the program

   print "%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s " % (cmd,
        arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9)

   # This might be where we specify cwd, but might have to create the directory first
   p = subprocess.Popen([cmd,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,arg8,arg9])

   # You are not using these, so why are you capturing them?
   # stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   # out, err = p.communicate()
   p.wait()

   stor_dir = new_dir + '/' + xdir

   # No need to call 3 external programs (shell, mkdir, mv) for this
   #subprocess.call(['mkdir '+stor_dir], shell=True)
   #subprocess.call(['mv *txt '+stor_dir],shell=True)
   os.mkdir(stor_dir)
   for fname in glob.iglob('*txt'):
       shutil.move(fname, stor_dir)


# Info on the parameters
this_run = """
Loop over %s
param1 = %s
param2 = %s
param3 = %s
param4 = %s
param5 = %s
param6 = %s
param7 = %s
param7 = %s
""" % (arg1, arg2 ,arg3 ,arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7, arg8, arg8)

# Are you sure this should be a binary file?
with open("this_run.info", "wb") as ofile:
    ofile.write(this_run)

# No need to call 2 external programs (shell, and mv) for this
#subprocess.call(['mv *.info '+new_dir],shell=True)
for fname in glob.iglob('*.info'):
    shutil.move(fname, new_dir)
```

If you want to move the files again, they can be done here.

Comment: This is really cool, thank you for this, I can see how these commands and syntax works in python and that's a big help. Only missing thing is: if I run this say twice, so i call `./run.py 1` and `./run.py 2` this will result in two distinct folder, but since the python script executes the software in the same working directory and the two executable print identically named files they might overwrite each other. Is there a ways to fix this (by making the executable run 'as if' it was launched in stor_dir directly so that there would be no need to move files?) Thank you again for the help!

Comment: Bonus: if I could just launch each iteration of the loop in parallel (instead of waiting for each one to finish) that would be awesome. Again, I think problem from above (overwriting files) might apply. I have never done a parloop with python, I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: @ThreeDiag: it is possible, but it would make things a more complex.  I think at this stage it would be best to keep it simple.

Comment: I uncommented my previous answer, maybe that explains better what I would like to achieve